# How do you use Python Multiprocessing for a function with zero positional arguments?

Tags: python, iterator, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Here is an example:

```
import multiprocessing
def function():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    p.map(function, )
```

yields the error: `TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'`

The function does not need any input, so I wish to not artificially force it to. Or does multiprocessing need some iterable?

The following code returns / prints nothing.  Why?

```
import multiprocessing
def function():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    p.map(function, ())
```

Comment: ... `map` requires an iterable to `map` a function onto... you don't *have* to use `map` if that's not what you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no arguments to pass in, you don't have to use `map`. You can simply use [`multiprocessing.Pool.apply`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply) instead:

```
import multiprocessing


def function():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
    p.apply(function)
```

Comment: But that just calls the function once.  The point of a pool is to run multiple copies simultaneously, no?

Answer (score 2):

If you are only trying to perform a small number of tasks, it may be better to use `Process` for reasons described [here](https://www.ellicium.com/python-multiprocessing-pool-process/).

[This site](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) provides an excellent tutorial on use of `Process()` which i have found helpful. Here is an example from the tutorial using your `function()`:

```
import multiprocessing
def function():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```